# Cannot assign object property to Vue 3 directive using dynamic key

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am using the `maska` npm to mask Vuetify input fields.

I have an object of masks I currently use:

```
export const Masks = {
    hour: { mask: "##:##", eager: true },
    host: { mask: "#00.#00.#00.#00", eager: true },
    port: { mask: "#0000" },
    cc: { mask: "#### #### #### ####" },
    ccName: { mask: "A A" },
    cvv: { mask: "###0" }
};
```

It works fine in the `<template>` part of a `.vue` file in this manner:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="model.start"
    v-maska:[Masks.hour]
/>
```

But in a dynamic form component I have written, I try to load the mask assigned to an input from it's model's object which is as follows:

```
const form = {
    start: {
        ...
        mask: Masks.hour,
        ...
    }
};
```

And in the template:

```
<div v-for="(field, index) in Object.keys(model)" :key="field">
    <v-text-field
        v-model="model[field].value"
        v-maska:[model[field].mask]
    />
</div>
```

Then I get this syntax error:

```
 ERROR  Internal server error: Error parsing JavaScript expression: Unexpected token, expected "]" (1:12)                                                                   4:59:07 p.m.  
  Plugin: vite:vue
  File: D:/Docs/Code/fresk/proteus/components/forms/dynamic-form.vue:98:13
  96 |                                  v-else-if="!model[field].type"
  97 |                                  v-model="model[field].value"
  98 |                                  v-maska:[model[field].mask]
     |               ^
  99 |                                  :name="field"
  100|                                  :label="model[field].label ? $t(model[field].label) : undefined"
      at createCompilerError (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.js:1332:17)
      at emitError (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.js:2822:5)
      at createExp (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.js:2815:7)
      at Object.ondirarg (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.js:2263:25)
      at Tokenizer.stateInDirArg (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.js:846:16)
      at Tokenizer.parse (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.js:1078:16)
      at Object.baseParse (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.js:2861:13)
      at Object.parse (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-dom\dist\compiler-dom.cjs.js:703:23)
      at Object.parse$2 [as parse] (D:\Docs\Code\fresk\proteus\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1851:24)
      at createDescriptor (file:///D:/Docs/Code/fresk/proteus/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:74:43)
```

My question is, how do I pass a variable value with an indexed array inside a v-for to a v-maska or any other Vue 3 directive?

Comment: Would you be able to create a *runnable* [mcve] showcasing the bug? We need mode detail on what the directive expects and how it is defined (at least specify the package defining it, along with the version you're using).

Comment: Another thing, in the code where you say it's working you're using `[Mask.hour]`, but the value asigned to `model[field].mask` is `[Mask.hours]`. Is that a typo in your code or only in the question?

Comment: Fixed the typo, sorry.

Comment: It's not really a bug it's a syntax problem.
I use Nuxt 3.9.3 with Typescript and Vuetify and Vue 3.4.15.

Comment: Well, we can argue on the definition of a bug all day long. I tend to consider a "bug" a difference between desired and actual output, given a particular input. Regardless of how we call it, if you need my help getting the desired outcome, a runnable minimal example would come in handy. Consider using codesandbox.io or similar. Where is `v-maska` defined?

Comment: v-maska is installed as per the documentation on their site for Nuxt 3:
https://beholdr.github.io/maska/#/?id=usage

It adds a directive to apply a mask to input fields.
Works when the options object is referenced in the template but not when referenced from the model.

I'll try a local reference and see.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by refactoring my `v-for` to this:

```
<div v-for="(field, key) in model" :key="key">
```

And then using it in the the template without the array index.

```
v-maska:[field.mask]
```

I guess we cannot use an array index as a value in the `[]` of a directive.